# Conexão com banco de dados - PDO

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

Galera, no curso, estamos manipulando banco de dados com PDO, mas agora na parte de conexão, me apareceu o `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` e não entendi muito bem pra que serve, só sei que a instancia do PDO pede isso no options. Mas pra que serve? O que ela faz exatamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-mysql.php):

> PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND (integer)
>
> Comando para executar ao se conectar no servidor MySQL. Irá ser executado novamente ao reconectar.
>
> Note que essa constante só pode ser usada no array driver_options ao
>   construir um novo manipulador de banco de dados.

Ou seja, é um comando `mysql` que vai ser executado apenas uma vez a cada conexão, logo que você se conectar (ou reconectar) ao servidor.

Exemplo de uso:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;port=3306', $user, $pass, 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  "SET NAMES 'UTF8'")
);
```

O comando `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` será rodado uma vez, sempre que essa uma nova conexão se iniciar.

Comment: Ok, Ricardo, obrigado! Mas ainda estou com dúvidas! Sei que ele vai executar uma vez ao se conectar, mas, o que ele faz? Ele so serve pra setar o banco de dados pra UTF8, etc...? Ou eu rodar o que eu quiser ali?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho você pode rodar qualquer comando válido.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado Ricardo!!

Answer (score 1):

**charset**

> Em versões anteriores ao PHP 5.3.6, esse elemento era ignorado de
>   forma silenciosa. O mesmo comportamente pode ser parcialmente
>   replicado com a opção PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, assim como o
>   exemplo a seguir demonstra.

** Configurando o character set como UTF-8 antes do PHP 5.3.6**

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    ); 

    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
?>
```

Com o `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` setamos apenas um que diz respeito ao charset utilizado pelo MYSQL, que será UTF8.